# PayPal RestAPI Sample Returns 404 for PayPal Payment

Tags: .net, api, rest, paypal, payment

I am new to PayPal development.  I am using the RestAPI sample project from GitHub for .NET and am attempting to complete a PayPal payment using the sample project.  I am able to create the payment and am redirected to the check out at the sandbox site.  After I login and select "continue" however, I receive 404 error -- INVALID_RESOURCE_ID.  Here are the details in JSON format:

```
{"name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","message":"The requested resource ID was not found","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","debug_id":"9b048f2d3407c"}
```

I also receive this same error when using my own credentials on my test site.  The payment seems to be created just fine using the RestAPI .NET sample and my own code:

```
{
  "id": "PAY-5P5661680K546313RKQ6V6NA",
  "create_time": "2014-10-14T17:36:52Z",
  "update_time": "2014-10-14T17:36:52Z",
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal",
    "payer_info": {
      "shipping_address": {}
    }
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "related_resources": [],
      "amount": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "total": "100.00",
        "details": {
          "shipping": "10.00",
          "subtotal": "75.00",
          "tax": "15.00"
        }
      },
      "description": "Transaction description.",
      "item_list": {
        "items": [
          {
            "quantity": "5",
            "name": "Item Name",
            "price": "15.00",
            "currency": "USD",
            "sku": "sku"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "state": "created",
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5P5661680K546313RKQ6V6NA",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-4WY238570T9571310",
      "rel": "approval_url",
      "method": "REDIRECT"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5P5661680K546313RKQ6V6NA/execute",
      "rel": "execute",
      "method": "POST"
    }
  ]
}
```

My assumption is that the sandbox for PayPal can execute PayPal payments.  Is this correct?  If so, how do I resolve this problem?

Comment: After you create the payment, are you using the `Payment` object returned from the `Payment.Create()` call to execute the payment?  Can you share a snippet of what your code looks like just before and after you call `Payment.Create()`?